# strong parameter and json input rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I am trying to save data through JSON String in which I have nested associated attributes. I do not want to use attr_accessible. I almost got the logic of strong parameter but still got the problem to make them work. I am getting JSON string and using it to save data using this

```
data = request.body.read
@inputData = Person.new(JSON.parse(data))
@inputData.save!
if@inputData.valid?
  render :status => 200, :json => "Data inserted successfully"
else
  render :status => 404, :json => "Not Inserted "
end
```

I have defined permit strong parameter method allow nested attributes like this

```
def referral_params
params.require(:person).permit(:id, user_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email], device_attributes: [:id, :os_type, :os_version], location_attributes: [:id, :latitude, :longitude], duration_attributes[:id, :start_time, :end_time]) end
```

But I am not sure how to use this regerral_params method along with JSON input string....

Comment: Where do you get `data` from? Is that POSTed?

Comment: yes it is POST method, "data = request.body.read" like this

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try changing your `referral_params` method to this:

```
def referral_params
  json_params = ActionController::Parameters.new( JSON.parse(request.body.read) )
  return json_params.require(:person).permit(:id, user_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email], device_attributes: [:id, :os_type, :os_version], location_attributes: [:id, :latitude, :longitude], duration_attributes[:id, :start_time, :end_time])
end
```

The first line inside the method parses your JSON (which returns a Ruby hash, if I remember correctly) and creates a new `ActionController::Parameters` object from that. The second one uses `permit` and `require` on that params-like object.

`params` is usually automatically created from post data key/value pairs, and will be of the type `ActionController::Parameters`. To use `permit` and `require`, you have to create an object of [that class](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) manually from a hash.

---

To then use these sanitized params, you have to change

```
@inputData = Person.new(JSON.parse(data))
```

to

```
@inputData = Person.new(referral_params)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems like it now working...just need to test it well